# Printing all permutations of True and False

Tags: java

I want to make a program that prints all permutations of true and false based on X length that is entered by the user. What I did was first initialize an array X elements long and initialize them all to true. Then I cycle thorough them to make the different permutations. The output is the array with all true and then it just prints false and the rest true eg

```
If X (length was 2)

true  true
false true
false true
false true
```

Here is my code.

```
import hsa.Console;

public class TorF {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    Console c = new Console();

    c.print("Length: ");
    int l = c.readInt();

    boolean[] values = new boolean[l];

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

        values[i] = true;
    }

    int numberOfPremutations = (int) Math.pow (2, l);

    for (int j = 0 ; j < numberOfPremutations ; j++) {

        for (int i = 0 ; i < l ; i++)
            System.out.print (values [i]);

        System.out.println ("");

        values[l - 1] = false;

        for (int i = l - 1 ; i > 0 ; i--) {

            if (values [i] == false) { 
                values [i - 1] = false;
                values [i] = true;


            }
        }

    }       

}

}
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: It's not printing all permutations of true and false based on the given length.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you explain what you wrote? Why do you think it will work? Try writing down a working algorithm... in words. Then work from that towards real code. By the way, these aren't permutations since the elements in your list aren't static. I would consider it to be similar to the notion of a powerset... which is also how I would code my solution.

Comment: What my thinking was (of what I wrote) was it would cycle through the array and if any element was true it would make the previous false and it true ultimately printing the permutations. Now that I put it to writing I see that it only produces half of them yet I don't know why it is printing this if the length is 3
/Code format isn't working but this is what it prints
        true true true *nl*
        false true true*nl*
        false true true *nl*
        false true true *nl*
        false true true *nl*
        false true true *nl*
        false true true *nl*
        false true true *nl*

Comment: "it would cycle through the array and if any element was true it would make the previous false and it true ultimately printing the permutations". 1) They're really not permutations. Look it up. 2) While your description is a bit vague, it definitely doesn't match what you wrote. Your code "iterates through the array _backwards_ and if any element, except the first one, is `false` then you set the previous element to `false` and the current element to `true`". As you've seen, your code will end up setting every element to `true` after the first iteration... other than the 0th element.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement it using addition because that's what you'd be reimplementing.  Then implement a way to map a binary number to a true, false values based on the value of the bit values at each position.  Using long would limit you to length of 63 (signed numbers).  If you need more than that use BigInteger (homework left to the reader of course).

```
for( long i = 0; i < permutations; i++ ) {
    printBinary( i, l );
}

public void printBinary( long number, int length ) {
    long current = 1 << length;
    while( current > 0 ) {
        System.out.print( number & current == current ? "true " : "false " );
        current >>> 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want `>>>` otherwise it'll only work for up to 62.

Answer (score 0):

Come on, guys, let's give the poor guy a break.

I think what you meant to write was something more like this:

```
for (int i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    System.out.print(values[i]);

System.out.println();

for (int i = 0 ; i < l ; i++) {
    if (values[i] == false) {
        values[i] = true;
        break;
    } else {
        values[i] = false;
    }
}
```

This could be made better still by noticing that what you're doing here is essentially just counting, *i.e.* 0, 1, 2, 3, *etc*.  For each binary number in the count, each bit of that number gives you one of the true/false values that you seek:

```
0 ==> 000 ==> false false false
1 ==> 001 ==> false false true
2 ==> 010 ==> false true  false
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at the problem that (hopefully) makes it crystal clear that what you're really doing is counting:

```
for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ZERO ; ! i.testBit(length) ; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    for (int j = length - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j--) {
        System.out.print( Boolean.valueOf( i.testBit(j) ).toString());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This approach has the advantage of working for very large lengths, as well.

Comment: I disagree with the statement that that's "what he's really doing". 1) The algorithm he described in the comments is not the algorithm you implemented in your other answer. 2) There exists a bijection between the set of all combinations of true and false with binary representations of numbers. Great. That doesn't mean that's the _only_ bijection. In fact there are `n!` such bijections (and that's only between those two sets). Using addition is a _convenient_ way to generate the `2^n` elements because it is so easy to code. Claiming that this is the _only_ way ("what you're really doing") is eh

Answer (score 0):

#### Could fail for some conditions,  but this is the soln which I found to print combinations of boolean variables.

```
package function;

public class PrintngAllCombinationOfTrueFalse {
    public static void printCombination(int num) {
        int permuteLen=(int) Math.pow(2,num);
        boolean b[]=new boolean[num];
        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
            b[i]=true;

        for(int j=0;j<permuteLen;j++){
            for( int i=0;i<num;i++)
                System.out.print("  "+b[i]+"  ");
            System.out.println(" ");

            for(int i=num-1;i>=0;i--){
                if(b[i]==true ){
                    b[i]=false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    b[i]=true;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String g[]){
        printCombination(3);
    }
}
```